# How to install both 64 and 32 bits version of Java at the same time?

Tags: java

I am trying to get a game to work (Wakfu). I tried to apply most of the info here, but nothing helped me at all. I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to install java32 run-time alongside java64.

Having only java32 installed is alright. If it is possible to have both Javas installed please tell me how to change between them. Thanks.

Comment: When it tells you "Java wrong version" what is the output of `java -version`?

Answer (score 0):

I have to apologize, i managed to find a solution to mi problem. I downloaded the game for the website as .tag.gz, untarred it and run it from the folder. All works now. No problems with java instances and runtime at all. Sorry for the turmoil.